# How to get status history/lineage for Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I was wondering if there is a `kubectl` command to quickly get the history of all `STATUS` for a given pod?

for example: Lets say a pod - `my-test-pod` went from `ContainerCreating` to `Running` to `OomKill` to `Terminating`:

I was wondering if there is a command that experts use to get this lineage. Appreciate a nudge..

Answer (score 5):

Using `kubectl get events` you can only see events of last 1 hour. If you want to persist events for a longer duration you can sue [eventrouter](https://github.com/heptiolabs/eventrouter).The event router serves as an active watcher of event resource in the kubernetes system, which takes those events and pushes them to a user specified sink. This is useful for a number of different purposes, but most notably long term behavioral analysis of your workloads running on your kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl get events` or `kubectl describe pod` which shows the events for the pod at the bottom. However events are only kept for a little while, so it's not a permanent history. For that you would need some webhooks or a tool like Prometheus.